# Double Click not working when Chrome Web Inspector Open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am currently trying to use the debugger in Chrome Web Inspector to view the code that is run after I trigger specific events in the browser. However, while I am able to inspect most DOM events, none of my "dblclick" events seems to be registering while I have the inspector window open.

Is anybody else experiencing this issue or have any idea why this is occcuring?

Comment: Did you try different browsers? Maybe Canary? Just to rule out it's not your browser settings/extensions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works fine on Canary. I tested both before I signed into my Google account and after I signed into my Google account as well. I tested both as I figured signing into my account would wire Canary up to all of the settings and extensions associated with my Chrome browser.

Comment: I'm seeing all kinds of weird issues with clicking, copy/paste, typing, etc... I removed all of my extensions on two separate machines and the issue is present.

Answer (score 11):

Solved. It turns out that when you enable the "Toggle device toolbar" you lose the ability to double click when Web Inspector is open. Turing the "Toggle device toolbar" feature back off allowed me to trigger "dblclick" events in the browser again

Answer (score 5):

Yep.  "Toggle device toolbar".
Here's an image of where you need to click to toggle it.

[image]