# Vue Js event listener

Tags: vue.js

I realized @dblclick not working on chrome. I tested same code on firefox and it worked OK.

Here is the piece of code

```
`<Tasks @toggle-reminder="toggleReminder" @delete-task="deleteTask" :tasks="tasks" />`

`toggleReminder(id){
         console.log('clicked'+id);
       }`
```

The event was emited like this fro an underlying Component:

```
`<div @dblclick="$emit('toggle-reminder', task.id)" :class="[task.reminder ? 'reminder' : '', 'task']">
       <h3>{{ task.text }}
           <i @click="$emit('delete-task', task.id)" class="fas fa-times"></i>
       </h3>
       <p>{{ task.day }}</p>
    </div>`
```

I am afraid it is navigator problem, as I said, it works good on firefox

I found that when I have the developer tool opened then dblclick event does not work, but when I close the developer tool then event work. Still weird

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660145/double-click-not-working-when-chrome-web-inspector-open) may help you

Comment: Thanks buddy. It worked after toggling the device manager. Now I can debug dblclick event while inspector is opened.